# I cant declare dynamically an array of vectors

Tags: c++, memory, vector, segmentation-fault, new-operator

My purpose is to create an adjacency list to represent a graph and i chose doing it by using vectors. My problem is that the number of vertices and edges of the graph is not always the same and it's given in input. Hence i try to declare the array of vectors dynamically. Here is my code(where N stands for the number of edges):

```
int N;
vector <int> *arr;
arr = new vector <int> [N];
cin >> N;`
```

Every time i try to handle a vector (ig `arr[0].push_back(3);`) i get a segmentation fault. What am i doing wrong :(

Edit: The N stands for the number of **nodes** and not the edges. This does not affect the segmentation error but only the way to represent the graph with vectors

Comment: First of you are using `N` before the user has input the value. Second off, why are you trying to use `new[]` here at all? Just use a `vector<vector<int>>` if you need dynamic sizes

Comment: Are you sure you're initializing `n` before calling `new`? Post the exact code that gives you an error.

Comment: Since you seem familiar with `std::vector` why not use it instead of `new[]`? You can use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there; but you're reading N *after* using it. A C++ program executes line-by-line, so when it comes to `new vector <int> [N]` the value `N` isn't read yet! In C++ terms you're then using an *uninitialized variable*, which is a form of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In C++, unlike most other languages, it is very easy to write a meaningless program and the compiler won't stop you (although it may issue a warning - pay attention to those!).

If you move `cin >> N;` to before `new vector <int> [N]` then it will work better, but wait, there's a better solution...

Instead of raw arrays, it is more idiomatic to have a vector of vectors. It is safer and also easier:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
int n;
cin >> n;
arr.resize(n);
```

Or simply declare the vector after `n` is known:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a dynamic `N` you can use a vector instead of an array:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(N);
arr[42].push_back(42);
```

Also make sure that your `N` variable is initialized otherwise you will encounter a out of bound access on `arr` which is likely the cause of the segfault.

Comment: Even after your edit, it doesn't solve the actual problem OP has … OP has UB since N is used before being given a value.

Comment: Well I'm assuming `N` has some value somehow... If `N` is not initialized then yeah you will have a out of bound access.

Comment: It's not an "out of bound access" … And why are you making the assumption that N has a value, when in OPs code, it clearly doesn't?

Comment: In my example if `N<42` then yeah you are doing an out of bound access on `arr`. In his question he states that `N` stands for the number of edges, so I am assuming that it is initialized somehow.

Comment: Sorry if i didnt make it clear, N is not initialized and its given as an input from a file.

Comment: Then you should make sure that `N` is well initialized